# Does Docker support for Windows Desktop Application?

Tags: c#, windows, docker, desktop-application

I have windows desktop application, and whenever I upgrade desktop application, user faces many problems like missing packages, and libraries. So, I want use Docker to deploy Windows application to user. I want know does Docker support for windows desktop application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory as long as application can be installed unattended it should be able to run on docker. Problem is that you will not be able to see GUI, so that makes running desktop application on docker pointless.

Edit : same question on [official docker forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-run-a-gui-application-on-docker/48437/6)